# Kubernetes localhost request inside a pod

Tags: kubernetes, xmlhttprequest

My kubernetes app consists on 2 apps deployed on the same pod, one of them sends and HTTP request to the other one, but there is no way to make the second one receive the request and send back a response successfully. It looks like kubernetes might be blocking localhost communication, since when I deploy it locally on my computer everything works.

As I've just said, I have a Kubernetes pod which deploys 2 files (the docker image already does that so it should be kind of transparent for k8s), one in python and the other one in express. What I want to do is to send an XMLHttpRequest from the express app to the python app when I change a select in the frontend. However, when I try to do so, I get a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8101/res. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

If I look under the network tab (in firefox development tools), I find that the OPTIONS request to localhost:8101 says CORS failed and the following POST request throwed an NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI. And there is no response headers either.

I've tried adding these statements to the python OPTIONS endpoint:

```
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin,authorization,content-type")
```

When I deploy it locally it works perfectly fine, but it seems like kubernetes is not allowing the http request to call http://127.0.0.1:8101, even though the pod has a loopback network interface.

I have tried different approaches but the main goal is to not hardcode any external IP, as pod IP may change with every deployment, but both apps are be deployed on the same machine so using localhost should be fine.

Is there a reason why kubernetes might be blocking the http requests? Or is it just that I am sending them wrong.

EDIT: Python app is sending info via socketio and it also works fine, even in Kubernetes, so it only doesn't work when using xmlhttprequest.

Comment: Localhost should work inside a pod, if you don't want to use different ip's you can just create a service and use the default dns provided by kubernetes
[link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Comment: @adamsranko it is ok if I hardcode localhost IP, but as I said it isn't working and I have no clue because it seems as if I'm calling the wrong IP:port. I've added an edit to the original question.

Comment: I just said that dns part, just in case it would work if you put them in separate pods. Btw when you say 2 app in 1 pod do you mean 1 pod with 2 container? or they run in the same container? Does it say 1/1 under the Ready column?

Comment: @adamsranko yes, 1 pod with 1 container, it says 1/1

Comment: Wait, it seems localhost:8081 is called directly from the browser, not by the backend pod. How could it be possibly routed to a kubernetes pod?!?

Comment: @Mafor wait true. I am doing the request from the frontend of the express app, so I am calling localhost:8101 from the frontend to reach python app that should be deployed in the same place than the frontend... unless that calling localhost:8101 calls client's localhost:8101, but that shouldn't be, right?

Comment: @Francisco From wherever your browser downloads the app, if you use `localhost` in the frontend, it will call the host of the browser. To call the host where the app is loaded from, you would need to use relative URL. But you cannot do it if the port is different: it's technically not "the same place".

Comment: @Mafor ok, thanks a lot! I am trying to change the way I am doing it